# Heat map R with a wide range

Tags: r, math, heatmap, stat

I am producing a heat map from this table

x

```
   .     0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8

  0    12820     720     807     879    1051     824     587     732     874
  1      557   38417   41289   44380   57301   42992   30805   41092   45616
  2       62   59575   83247   72433   95751   76113   50002   92921   72773
  3       23   45346  100836   57101   57903   50625   35223   52695   47868
  4        4   14718   40000   13135    5985   13188   19252    8044    7095
  5        0    4459    6828     674     890    5251    4959     399     563
  6        0     216     333     142     115     189     202     128     128
  7        0     188      97      30      57     255      19      51      29
  8        1      20      38      13       7       4      11      44      17
  9        0      11       9       1       0       8      12     102       6
  10    7992    9620   16841   11065    9917    9619    8133    9291    8554

           9      10

  0        6   10804
  1       55   26041
  2       33   45915
  3       17   35198
  4        1   10071
  5        0    2092
  6        0     102
  7        0      29
  8        0       1
  9        1       1
  10     487 1319070
```

With this code

```
hv <- heatmap.2(x, col=cm.colors(255), scale="none",trace='none', density="none",lmat=rbind( c(0, 3), c(2,1), c(0,4) ), lhei=c(1.5, 4, 2 ),Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE,dendrogram = "none",margins=c(5,5),xlab="ICOADS ship speed indicator",ylab="ICOADS course indicator")
```

I produce this plot

[image]

which is not very useful. Anyway, if I don't want to put scale ="row" or scale="column" because it will be hard to interpret the result. Is there a way of using scale="none" and seeing different ranges of colours?

Thanks

Comment: please provide output from a `dput(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's one way using `ggplot`.

[image]

```
library(reshape2)       # for melt
library(RColorBrewer)   # for brewer.pal(...)
library(ggplot2)

x  <- cbind(id=as.numeric(rownames(x)),x)
gg <- melt(x,id="id")
gg$variable <- as.numeric(substr(gg$variable,2,4))
brks   <- c(0,10^rep(0:7))
gg$bin <- cut(gg$value,breaks=brks,labels=0:7,include.lowest=T)

ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=factor(id),y=factor(10-variable),fill=bin))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="",labels=brks,values=rev(brewer.pal(8,"Spectral")))+
  scale_y_discrete(labels=10:0)+
  labs(x="",y="")+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.border=element_blank())
```

The basic idea is to use a logarithmic scale for the colors. This is a bit of a problem for you because you have zeros. So a work-around sets bins using the `cut(...)` function. The bin breaks are set to 0,1,10,100,...,1e7.

Your data is in "wide" format: different values of "y" in different columns, whereas `ggplot` needs the data in "long" format: all the data in one column with x-values and y-values in separate columns. We convert wide to long using the `melt(...)` function. The rest of the code sets up the bins and the labels, and formats the plot to make it look as close to yours as I could manage.